# Microsoft Release Management 2015 client auto refresh not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ms-release-management

I recently upgraded Microsoft Release Management from 2013 to 2015 (client, server and agents upgraded). I have noticed that the 2015 client no longer automatically refreshes the screen while a release it running.  One has to click the release button to get an update on any running release jobs.

I've looked all over for a setting or configuration item that will turn this on.  Has this feature been removed?  Does anyone know how to enable the setting in the 2015 client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been removed. There is no way to re-enable it on the 2015 client.

However, RM on VSO will provide that feature.